# Android getIntent() returns current activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a question about getIntent();
Somebody makes activity(Activity A) to call my Activity(Activity B). So it's different package name. The problem is that when I use getIntent(), the return of getIntent is Activity B. so intent.getExtras() is null. 
What is problem? I think getIntent() should return Activity A.
It's good work to start from Activity A to B.

Activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(B Package, B Activity);
intent.putExtra("Test", test);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OK);
```

---

Activity B

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Log.d(TAG, "" +getIntent());
if(intent.getExtras() != null){
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("Test");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The getIntent() method does not return an Activity, it returns an Intent.  If you look at the documentation, it returns the Intent that started the current Activity.  So, when you call getIntent() in Activity B, it returns the Intent that was created in Activity A that was used to start Activity B.    See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()   and here:   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()

Comment: @ Daniel Nugent you're right. It returns intent. But I tried to Log adbout getIntent(). It returns activity B intent, not activity A intent.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that?  Show the log output....

Comment: You aren't by any chance getting confused by the ouput. e.g. in the Answer (Results i.e. Log extract) **`getIntent()`** returns `cmp=mike092015.app001/.testIntent` from **testIntent** activity. I believe that's not the calling activity but the owning activity that gets output?

Comment: @MikeT That's right, the owning activity is output as you told.

Answer (score 1):

**Activity A** as

```
public void testIntentCall(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,testIntent.class);
        intent.putExtra("TEST","test");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

with **Activity B** as

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("INTENT TEST","Intent Passed=>" + getIntent().toString());
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getExtras() != null) {
        Log.d("INTENT TEST", "Intent Extras=>" +intent.getExtras().toString());
        Log.d("INTENT TEST", "Intent Extra TEST =>" + intent.getStringExtra("TEST"));
    }
    finish();
}
```

Results in  :-

```
06-02 13:45:40.615 11027-11027/mike092015.app001 D/INTENT TEST: Intent Passed=>Intent { cmp=mike092015.app001/.testIntent (has extras) }
06-02 13:48:00.531 11027-11027/mike092015.app001 D/INTENT TEST: Intent Extras=>Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]
06-02 13:48:00.531 11027-11027/mike092015.app001 D/INTENT TEST: Intent Extra TEST =>test
```

So the issue appears to be with either `setClassName` or `StartActivityForResult`.

Tested using `StartActivityForResult(intent,0)` or **1** runs OK with the same results. So the issue appears to be with `setClassname`.

I'm wondering if the issue is that Activity B, due to the Class component invoked, based upon `B Package, B Activity` being set/passed, is starting another Activity B from Activity B and thus it's parent might then be itself. Perhaps the log contains 2 messages and perhaps the first shows A as the caller activity.

**What B Package and B Activity are , is likely crucial in determining the issue.**

Comment: It's impossible to call just getExtras. I have a error as getExtras() is undefined

Comment: I believe you are wrong, according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html the method getIntent() returns the intent that started the activity.

Comment: @ Buildersrejected,  Yes you're right. But the problem is that it can't return  started the activity. As I said, it returns current activity.

Comment: Some actual working code `final String caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("Caller");
        shopid = getIntent().getLongExtra("SHOPID", -1);`  No intent created. Perhaps you haven't done yours after `onCreate` and then `super.onCreate()` in B.

Comment: @MikeT the root problem is that getIntent() is current activity. That's why getStringExtra is not working and I call super.onCreate() in OnCreate()

Comment: @user3796216 when I originally posted I missed `getIntent()`, before the `getExtras` and `getStringExtras`. Have you tried as per amended answer? Without `getIntent()`, yes `getStringExtras()` doesn't work.

Comment: @MikeT It's also not working, I don't know why getIntent() returns current activity.

Comment: My suggestion, 1) delete `intent.setClassName(B Package, B Activity);` from **A**. 2) try just `startActivity(intent)` i.e. without `ForResult` 3) make sure you haven't got `Intent intent = getIntent()` coded. If this works then you can try re-adding and then find out where it goes askew.

Comment: Same as previous but a little more specific. My suggestion, 1) delete `intent.setClassName(B Package, B Activity);` from **A**. 2) try just `startActivity(intent)` i.e. without `ForResult` in **A**. 3) make sure you haven't got `Intent intent = getIntent()` coded in **B**. If this works then you can try re-adding and then find out where it goes askew.

Comment: The problem is that I can't modify Activity A

Comment: @user3796216 I'm trying to replicate. See what I can come up with.

Comment: @MikeT thanks for answering, I think your answer is correct. So I've tryed to how to solve this problem